# TypeError: this.state.toLocaleTimeString is not a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

This is code displaying what time is.

I set `state` to *new Date()* and give `setState()`  *new Date()* as a parameter.

```
class Clock extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = new Date()

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(()=> this.tick(), 1000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID)
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState(new Date())
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>It is {this.state.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    )
    
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Running code, getting error like below

*TypeError: this.state.toLocaleTimeString is not a function*

```
Clock.render
  29 | return (
  30 |   <div>
  31 |     <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
> 32 |     <h2>It is {this.state.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
     | ^  33 |   </div>
  34 | )
  35 |
```

I can't understand what problem is.

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using any key to store/update the state, which is causing this error, since React doesn't find anything to update. I've used the key `date` to store and update the state on every second.

so, the state will be

```
this.state = {
  date: new Date()
};
```

and the tick function update.

```
tick() {
  this.setState({ date: new Date() });
}
```

and also the rendering part to use the state key.

```
<h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
```

Your updated code should be something like below.

```html
import { render } from "react-dom";
import React from "react";

class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date()
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({ date: new Date() });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<Clock />, rootElement);
```

React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) has some useful information regarding the state management and other related topics, which you should definitely take a look at, to understand how state works and re-renders UI accordingly.

Comment: Why we should use key to update the state? `this.setState(new Date())` also update the state. I can't differentiate between Using key to update and giving directly `new Date()` as a parameter.

Comment: You should probably take a look at the react docs to understand, how `setState` works. When you call the `setState` function, it needs some sort of identifier to update the relevant part of the state. Without passing any identifier to `setState` e.g. in this case `this.setState(new Date())`, we're providing an updated state without an identifier, it'll likely to cause some unexpected behavior/changes to the state.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this.state = {date: new Date()};` in your state declarations instead.